# Cannot open database "lolo2013_db1.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: asp.net

After uploading when I try to browse my website I get this error

> Login failed for user 'DOTNETSPIDER1\lolo2013'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "lolo2013_db1.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'DOTNETSPIDER1\lolo2013'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

How can I solve it???

My `web.config` file:

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ConnectionString" 
       connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=lolo2013_db1.mdf"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
 <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <compilation defaultLanguage="vb" debug="true" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" /> 
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" /> <!-- Allow all users -->
    </authorization>
    <trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true" />
    <sessionState 
            mode="InProc"
            stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
            sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes"
            cookieless="false" 
            timeout="10" 
    />
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you show your web.config? The connection string should pass the username and password.

Comment: Does your web hosting has support for SQL Compact? an old that I used didn't and really had to create a new database within their shared Microsoft SQL platform...

Comment: yes i used aspspider.com

Comment: you are using  a SQL Express connection string, and `.\SQLExpress` means `localhost`. Check with your hosting what is their server database and change accordinlgy (I'm sure they have "How to" on that) or change to a [SQL Compact connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-compact/) is you are using a file instead of a database

Comment: Initial Catalog should be the name of the Database not the name of the File. Are you sure that your database is named in that way?

Comment: @balexandre why do you think he is using Sql Compact?

Comment: I copy the connection string from the provider and I use a database not a file

Comment: @Steve yes its the same name of my database

Comment: If you're using a **database** on the server, you should **definitely NOT**  include the `.mdf` extension in your `Initial Catalog=lolo2013_db1.mdf` - just use `Initial Catalog=lolo2013_db1` (or whatever the database name on the server is)